# C passing other c program as main argv

Tags: c, shell, gcc, arguments

Just a curiosity,

Consider that I have

> ./first
>
> ./second

that they are  executable c program

first.c:

```
char main(void){
    return '5';
}
```

second.c:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv){
    printf("%s", argv[2]);
    return 0;
}
```

(I want to print 5 here)

Is it possible to compile second.c like:

```
gcc second.c -./first
```

Of course I know that wont work but is it possible to write something that will work like what I want?

Comment: `char main(void)` where did you get that?

Comment: You're looking for the pipe operator in your shell (or `$()`)

Comment: @SouravGhosh I know it is strongly wrong but to express my idea I used char main(void) since I want to use returned value from other c program.

Comment: remove first.c, rename the function as `char * non_main(void)` and call that in second.c, least troublesome way.

Comment: You can use the standard `int main(...)` since `'5'` is an `int` expression, as `printf("%zu\n", sizeof('5'));` will reveal.

Comment: If you want to run the second program from the first, use `system()`.

Comment: @İhsanCemilÇiçek: `char main(void)` is an invalid signature (I wonder if your compiler did not warn). Using a wrong function signature invokes undefined behaviour. If you knew it was wrong, you intentionally broke your code.

Comment: @SLaks can you explaine a little bit more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return value of `main()` becomes the program's exit status, which is put in the shell's `$?` variable. So it should be:

```
./first
./second $?
```

You should change `first.c` to return an `int`, not `char`; otherwise it will print the ASCII code for the `'5'` character, not `5`.

```
int main(void){
    return 5;
}
```

And in `second.c`, it should be `argc[1]`, not `argv[2]`.

Comment: So that $? Exit status of latest programs which has finished. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have the first program print "5":

```
int main(void){
    printf("5\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Then you can use backquotes in the shell to put the output of this program into the parameters of the other:

```
./second `./first`
```